# Motherboard or processor failing?

Tags: linux, cpu, motherboard

I have an AMD A10-5800K 3.8Ghz on a Gigabyte GA-F2A88X-D3H board. I've been using it for about 4 years without problem. Yesterday it refused to start the kernel, rebooting on the `Loading initrd` stage.

At first I thought it could be something related with the hard drives. I have two HD, one with dual Windows/Linux boot and the other, an SSD with only Linux, but all of them failed in the same way.

I made a Fedora usb boot disk and the same happened, reboot in `Loading initrd`. With that Fedora disk I did a memtest, and everything reported ok.

Finally I found that starting the kernel with `maxcpus=1` solved the problem, but of course i just have one of the four available cores.

So, I assume it is a HW question. My doubt now is, what is failing, the motherboard or the processor ? I tend to think that is a mobo problem, but without a solid argument, just I saw lot more mobos failing than processors.

Having no other equipment, what can I do to discard, i.e, a processor problem ? Or would it be safe to discard it already and just buy a new mobo ?

Comment: I think you mean cores not CPUs because you only have a single CPU installed on that motherboard.  The fact it works indicates neither the motherboard nor the CPU is at fault.

Comment: Correct, I've edited the question. Ops. Then, what could be the problem ? Maybe the power source failing to provide enough power for several cores ?

Comment: Have you tried checking your BIOS settings or resetting it?

Comment: @perencia I could speculate until I am blue in the face but it still would be a guess.  You asked our opinion, since my opinion makes a horrible answer, I submitted a comment

Comment: Hard to tell...it could be a bad core (that you disable hen going single-core) or a mobo problem that is mitigated when running with a single core (less frequent access to some hardware), or, as you say a power problem. In decreasing order of failure probability: power supply, mobo, processor....

Comment: CPU failure without external cause is rare; I suspect a heat problem (fan, paste). If it overheated in the past, that could also have damaged it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post an answer, though I'm not 100% sure if that's correct it can be helpful for someone on the same situation.

Finally I bought another mobo and installed the CPU. The problem persisted on the same terms.

Using the fedora Troubleshooting option of the image I got more details. I transcribe them (omiting addresses)

```
mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 1: Machine Check Exception: 4 Bank 0:...
mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC ... ADDR ... MISC ...
mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:... TIME .... SOCKET 0 APIC 1 microcode ....
```

Then I found how to do [cpu hotplug](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/core-api/cpu_hotplug.html) on Linux.

My solution has been to start the kernel with `maxcpus=1` and then create a startup script to bring the third and fourth cores online. If I try to wake up the second core, I end with the same problem, so I guess that core is been damaged (how I cannot tell).

This solution has a pair of drawbacks, but I'm fine with them.

- Obviosly, I lost one core.
- I cannot run Windows.